# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for accessing js file from different domain

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cors

I have been trying to access a JS file on `domain 2` in my application which is on `domain 1`.

After several attempts, I am getting the following error.

> Script from origin 'http://domain2.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domain1.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I have been trying different methods which made me modify my `.htaccess` file but no luck.

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: How are you loading it that a js file reference is giving you that error?

Comment: Same-origin policy generally doesn't apply for source files in script tags, so you must be using ajax or something similar, and then the question becomes "why" ? Also, what does the .htaccess file have to do with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a js file using Ajax, for example your are loading module with AMD you are most probably facing [Same-origin policy restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

In this case you should [enable cross-origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/) at the server side.

If you are loading a .js file in your HTML like this:

```
<script src="http://domain1.com/file.js"></script>
```

No restriction Same-origin policy applies and you should be able to load your script with no problems (you find example of this usage when loading a js library, example jQuery from a CDN in your web page).